# PHP, MySQL, Array from HTML Form in Search Query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search-engine

I have a search engine with an html form that sends data to a PHP script the queries a MySQL database. In the html form, I have a  option that allows multiple selections. Thus far, I have put square brackets after the name in the HTML in order to make it an array. But I think there is a problem in the PHP because results are not correct.

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" name='category[]'>
      <option>Literature</option>
      <option>History</option>
      <option>Science</option>
      <option>Fine Arts</option>
      <option>Trash</option>
      <option>Mythology</option>
      <option>Phylosophy</option>
      <option>Social Science</option>
      <option>Religion</option>
      <option>Geography</option>
  </select>
```

search.php

```
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search'];

}

if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b><em>$search</em></b> and ";
mysql_connect("fake","fake","fake");
mysql_select_db("quinterestdb");}

mysql_real_escape_string($search);

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="Answer LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND Answer LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$cat = $_GET ['category'];
$comma_separated = implode("','", $cat);

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM tossups WHERE $construct AND Category IN('$comma_separated')";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);
```

When I use the search engine, the script runs just fine, but there are still results that have categories that were not selected. Any idea?

Comment: What is the form method? Are you using POST or GET?

Comment: can you print $constructs and run in phpmyadmin.

Comment: GET is default. You don't have to specify.

Comment: What is in the $construct variable?

Comment: `option` tag should have `value` attribute assigned, in `implode` double-quotes are extra, your script is vulnerable to sql injection, you use deprecated `mysql` API.

Comment: I edited it to show what is in $construct

Comment: @PLB But these are not values, they are strings? In the database, they are stored as strings (varchar)

Comment: @Rajeev Ranjan I did.

Comment: @user2483916 you did in your code echo it on your side and tell us what it contains and one more thing if the values in options coming from data base say $option1
so you should code it as "<option value='".$option1."'>".$option1."</option>"

Comment: @RajeevRanjan When I print $constructs, I get:

Comment: SELECT * FROM tossups WHERE Answer LIKE '%washington%' AND Category IN('Literature','History') <--- example I did just now. When I run this in phpMyAdmin, all the results are correct and categories are correct, but on the webpage, I get results with other categories.

Comment: /search.php?search=washington&submit=Search&category%5B%5D=Literature&category%5B%5D=History <--- URL since GET retrieves from URL.

Comment: @user2483916 if this query is being used for webpage then simply not possible different answer for phpmyadmin and on webpage..

Comment: Try using 'POST' method in your form and hope that will fix it

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way. Should be something like this, with VALUE

```
<select multiple="multiple" name='category[]'>
      <option value="v1">Literature</option>
      <option value="v2">History</option>
...
  </select>
```